# Taking ArcGIS feature class to pandas pivot table?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, pandas, pivot-table

I'm new to pandas and am trying to create a pivot table based off of two fields - DIVISION and MATERIAL. I'd like to count each occurances of each value. Rows would be DIVISION and columns would be MATERIAL.

Example:

[image]

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
import arcpy
import pandas

#path to feature class
servFc = r"Path\to\featureclass"
#create numpy array
npArray = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(servFc,
                                            ["MATERIAL", "DIVISION"],
                                            null_value = -9999)

#numpy array to pandas data frame
pandaDf = pandas.DataFrame (npArray)
#pivot table - guessing here
pandas.pivot_table (pandaDf, index = "DIVISION", columns = "MATERIAL", aggfunc = numpy.sum) #<--- want count, not sum
```

Results:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Comment: This got closed while I was answering - you're just missing one parameter in your pivot_table call (and a slight change to the aggfunc).  Try this:  pandas.pivot_table (pandaDf, values = None, index = "DIVISION", columns = "MATERIAL", aggfunc ='count')

Comment: @AlecZ I get the same result with your code - `Empty DataFrame`

Comment: This may or may not be your problem (I've not done more than `import pandas`) but it sounds like it may be in the right vicinity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040534/pandas-pivot-table-returns-empty-dataframe

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/51315554/820534

Comment: @PolyGeo I posted on StackOverflow as instructed once the question was put on hold.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, I actually liked your question a lot (because it may trigger me to look at pandas one day), even though it is technically off-topic.  My "all ArcPy" approach to answering your question would have been to use a search and insert cursor to rearrange your table into three columns (perhaps DIVISION, MATERIAL, QUANTITY) and then use Summary Statistics with two case fields on that.

Comment: @PolyGeo Yeah that's the way I've done it but it's very slow and I can tell already that numpy/pandas is the much better approach.

Comment: I'm keen to see any answer you get at SO, and if you post any performance timing as a comment or by revising this Q&A to be about working around a performance bottleneck encountered using the all ArcPy way.

Comment: @PolyGeo The question has been answered on StackOverflow (twice, both valid).